# Spark cache() doesn't work when used with repartition()

Tags: apache-spark, caching, pyspark

The spark cache() function when used along with the repartition() doesn't cache the dataframe. Can anyone explain why this happens?

Edit:

```
df.repartition(1000).cache()
df.count()
```

I have tried doing them on separate lines and that works.

Edit:

```
df2 = df1.repartition(1000)
df2.cache()
df2.count()
```

I expected the dataframe to be cached but i can't see it in the storage on UI

Comment: have you called an action on `df2`? Remember that `cache` is lazy: a dataset will be cached only when an action (eg. `count`) is called on it

Comment: I did an action on this. I called ```df.count()``` in the next line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dataframes are immutable like RDD, So though you are calling repartition on df, you are not assigning it to any DF and the current df will not change.

```
df.repartition(1000).cache()
df.count()
```

Above one won't work.

```
df.repartition(1000)
df.cache()
df.count()
```

For above code if you check in storage, it wont show 1000 partitions cached. Storage will show the cached partitions as **df.rdd.getNumPartitions**(which will be not 1000).

So try this.

```
val df1 = df.repartition(1000).cache()
df1.count()
```

This should work.

Comment: thank you so much. this answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You have to call an action so that the cache will be triggered. 
do:

```
df2 = df1.repartition(1000)
df2.cache().count()
```

Comment: I did an action on this. I called df.count() in the next line. Doing both in the same line won't cache

Comment: Is there any data in df1?